# Accessing index of an array

Tags: assembly, masm

I'm new to assembly language and my class is based on MASM. My objective is to get the index of an array from the user input.

```
.data
myDates BYTE 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

.code
main PROC

Month:
mov edi, ecx                ; edi = ecx copy counter 

mov edx, OFFSET disMonth        ; edx = disMonth
call WriteString            ; write ax
call ReadInt                ; eax = user input

cmp eax, 12             ; no, is eax > 12
JA  ErrorMonth              ; yes, jmp to ErrorMonth
cmp eax, 0              ; no, is eax > 0
JA CalMonth             ; yes, jmp to CalMonth

ErrorMonth:
mov edx, OFFSET errMsg              ; edx = errMsg
call WriteString            ; display edx
jmp Month               ; jmp back to Month

CalMonth:
                    ; calculating (m + 9) % 12
add eax, 9              ; eax += 9
mov edx, 0              ; edx = 0
mov ecx, 12             ; ecx = 12
div ecx                 ; eax = Q & edx = R

mov ebx, edx                ; ebx = edx *Month Storage*



Day:
mov edx, OFFSET disDay              ; edx = disDay
call WriteString            ; write edx
call ReadInt                ; eax = user input

mov ebp, eax                ; ebp = eax *Day Storage*

movzx eax, monthDate[ebx - 1]
call WriteInt

cmp ebp, eax                ; is ebp > eax
JA ErrorDay             ; jmp to ErrorDay
jmp Year                ; jmp to Year
```

If ebx == 12 for some reason the output is 9 and not 12. But when I replace `ebx - 1` with 11, it prints 12 like it should. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I get 12.  Show the rest of the routine, i.e. getting user input and converting that from ASCII to decimal, and your routine you use to print the results.

Comment: @Gunner I just added my the rest of my code. Sorry if I'm just using register. The hw requires me to only use registers. There are a view more data declared in .data, but they're just strings.

Comment: @Gunner, I know what I did wrong now. It's because I'm using the answer from after the `CalMonth` that's why it's 9.

Answer (score -2):

As [Nathan said in their last comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21641715/accessing-index-of-an-array/55599068#comment32706943_21641715):

> It's because I'm using the answer from after the `CalMonth` that's why it's 9.